# Visual Studio Code - Set default syntax for .scss files

Tags: visual-studio-code

Problems setting default syntax for `.scss` files.

Reading the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers) and this is how you should set it:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.scss": "Sass (indented)"
},
```

But it not works. Have anyone similar problems?

When I try to change syntax manually (clicking right bottom corner) it appears as `Sass (indented)` maybe in system it has another name? like `sass_indented` or `sass indented` or e.t.c.

*None of this does not work for me.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just saas?

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.scss": "sass"
}
```

Or press ctrl+space to bring up the IntelliSense to show the available language identifiers [[Ref](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview#_adding-a-file-extension-to-a-language)].

Comment: Thanks `ctrl+space` helped me.